# What's wrong with this differentiation?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I had the following question in an exam.

> **Exercise 2.** Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function such that $\nabla g(2, 1) = (0, 4)$ and whose Hessian matrix is $Hg(2, 1) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. Calculate $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(1, 1)$, where $f(x, y) = g(x + y, \frac{y}{x})$.

**My attempt:**
By the chain rule:
$$f_x = g_x - \frac{y}{x^2}g_y.$$
Now differenting with respect to $x$:
$$f_{xx}=g_{xx} - y\frac{x^2g_{xy}-2xg_y}{x^4}.$$
Giving $f_{xx}(1,1)=1-(-1-2*4)=10$.

But the teacher said that $f_{xx}(1,1)=14$!!! I'm bugging since it seems so obvious to me: apply the chain rule, fix $y$ and then treat $g_x$ as a function in one variable in order to differentiate it with respect to $x$. So what am I missing here? If there's any mistake it must be in the second step.

Comment: Hint: When you write down $f_x = g_x - \frac{y}{x^2}g_y$, if you do it more precisely, that is, $f_x(x, y) = g_x(u, v) - \frac{y}{x^2}g_y(u, v)$, what are $u$ and $v$? Are they just $x$ and $y$ or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$h(x,y):=\left(x + y, \frac yx\right),$$ so that $f=g\circ h$. Then,
$f_x(x,y)$ is not equal to $g_x(x,y)-\frac y{x^2}g_y(x,y)$. Instead,
$$f_x(x,y)=(g_x\circ h)(x,y)-\frac y{x^2}(g_y\circ h)(x,y)$$
hence
$$f_{xx}(x,y)=(g_{xx}\circ h)(x,y)-2\frac y{x^2}(g_{xy}\circ h)(x,y)+\left(-\frac y{x^2}\right)^2(g_{yy}\circ h)(x,y)+\frac{2y}{x^3}(g_y\circ h)(x,y),$$
giving
$$f_{xx}(1,1)=\left(g_{xx}-2g_{yx}+g_{yy}+2g_y\right)(2,1)\\
=1-2(-1)+3+2\cdot4=14.$$

Comment: Right thanks Anne. I forgot to apply the chain rule to the partials of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$f_{xx}=g_{xx} - \frac{y}{x^2}g_{xy}+ \frac{2y}{x^3}g_y- \frac{y}{x^2}\left(g_{xy} - \frac{y}{x^2}g_{yy}\right)=g_{xx} - \frac{2y}{x^2}g_{xy}+ \frac{2y}{x^3}g_y+ \frac{y^2}{x^4}g_{yy}$$

therefore

$$f_{xx}(1,1)=1-2\cdot (-1)+2\cdot 4+1\cdot3=14$$